# Triangle inequality for tensor products

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, triangle-inequality

Suppose that $f,g,h,l\in L^1$ are *positive* and *normalized* (PDFs) functions. Then, how can I prove the following "triangle inequality"?

$|f(x)g(y) - h(x) l(y)|\leq |f(x)-h(x)| + |g(y)-l(y)|$?

If this is true, is the positivity condition necessary or it can be dropped?

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality follows by the following calculation.

$$|ab-cd|=|ab-cb+cb-cd|\le|a-c||b|+|c||b-d|\le|a-c|+|b-d|,$$
where $a=f(x)$, $b=g(y)$, $c=h(x)$ and $d=l(y)$.

The proof only uses the triangle inequality for numbers and that $b$ and $c$ have absolute value smaller or equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you! That is neat!